# How to get a list of files on the server with angularjs and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'd like to create a dropdown list of files available in a directory on the server.

I believe this is possible using

```
fs.readFile()
```

However, in my controller I dont seem to have access to fs.

When I do this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

I get an error as the following:

Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

How can I allow fs to be loaded in my controller js file?

Comment: The fs part would have to be on the node side, then you'd need to make an http/https call to get the list to the angular client.

Comment: Not perfectly clear from your question, but it looks like your Angular controller, controller.js is being evaluated on the client side. Node's `fs` is on the server. You'll want to use an  service/resource on the angular side which would call to your node app, which would be responsible for generating/sending the file list.

Comment: @barry-johnson yes youre right. It seems like I can call and query files from the js file that node is serving. Now I need to figure out how to call that function from my client side controller. I'll try creating a service as you suggested. Thanks :)